# Doing some performance tuning and don't know how to find where time is being spent

Tags: xpages, jsf-1.2

I've had some complaints about response time with an application, so I'm looking into where I can speed things up. Using a profiling phase listener and some profiling wrappers, I expected to find some things that needed to be cached. However that doesn't seem to be the case. A typical example run looks something like this:

```
Controller>afterRestoreView completed in 0:00.000.044769
PhaseProfiler>LIFECYCLE>RESTORE_VIEW completed in 0:00.017.090231
PhaseProfiler>LIFECYCLE>APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES completed in 0:00.012.076884
PhaseProfiler>LIFECYCLE>PROCESS_VALIDATIONS completed in 0:00.003.804324
PhaseProfiler>LIFECYCLE>UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES completed in 0:00.002.898762
PhaseProfiler>LIFECYCLE>INVOKE_APPLICATION completed in 0:00.000.113143
Controller>beforeRenderResponse completed in 0:00.000.012222
Controller>afterRenderResponse completed in 0:00.000.003143
Counted resolves: 4975
Top ten most expensive resolves: 
Total took a total of 0:00.020.281386s
flashScope took a total of 0:00.006.770973s
caseBean took a total of 0:00.004.517358s
caseFilter took a total of 0:00.003.038453s
row took a total of 0:00.001.741708s
session took a total of 0:00.001.026528s
compositeData took a total of 0:00.000.983215s
uiService took a total of 0:00.000.641919s
requestScope took a total of 0:00.000.391530s
options took a total of 0:00.000.176558s
PhaseProfiler>LIFECYCLE>RENDER_RESPONSE completed in 0:02.900.494895
PhaseProfiler>LIFECYCLE completed in 0:02.936.944360
```

So something in RenderResponse is taking about 2.9 seconds, but it isn't my event handlers and it isn't my variable bindings. Using System.nanoTime isn't exactly performant but it seems to add about a second or less in comparison to System.currentTimeMillis, so I'm still missing quite a bit of time. I can only account for less than 21ms.

Are there techniques for digging deeper?

Answer (score 3):

Use this project: https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Toolbox

Although I wasn't able to make the agent work on R9, its CPU profiler does a perfect job. It can pinpoint bottlenecks to specific SSJS, Java method or Notes API call. Highly recommended.

Comment: I'm still on 8.5.3 so no R9 is a feature, not a bug :D.

Comment: XPages Toolbox should work on 8.5.2+. The key elements are putting the database in the right location (the root), pointed to from the jar file, whose location is defined in the text configuration file that needs to go in the Domino program folder, pointed to from the notes.ini. There also needs to be a change to the java security policy (this may just be for changing logging levels). Consequently, it's not recommended for production servers.